# scss builder for cloud9 web editor

Tags: css, compiler-errors, sass, cloud9-ide

Hey there :) I'm trying to figure out how I can make a scss builder for cloud9. I could only find something for less here on stackoverflow.

I'm trying to get main.scss in my scss folder to be compiled into main.css in a css folder at the same level.

The builder:

```
{
    "caption" : "SCSS",
    "cmd": ["scss", "$file", "-x", "${file/\\.scss/\\.css/}"],
    "selector": "source.scss"
}
```

Error:

OptionParser::InvalidOption: invalid option: -x
  Use --trace for backtrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you're using the Cloud9 builder is correct, however, I couldn't find the -x option within `scss`. Here's what `scss -h` gives me:

```
Usage: scss [options] [INPUT] [OUTPUT]

Description:
  Converts SCSS or Sass files to CSS.

Common Options:
    -I, --load-path PATH             Specify a Sass import path.
    -r, --require LIB                Require a Ruby library before running Sass.
        --compass                    Make Compass imports available and load project configuration.
    -t, --style NAME                 Output style. Can be nested (default), compact, compressed, or expanded.
    -?, -h, --help                   Show this help message.
    -v, --version                    Print the Sass version.

Watching and Updating:
        --watch                      Watch files or directories for changes.
                                     The location of the generated CSS can be set using a colon:
                                       scss --watch input.scss:output.css
                                       scss --watch input-dir:output-dir
        --poll                       Check for file changes manually, rather than relying on the OS.
                                     Only meaningful for --watch.
        --update                     Compile files or directories to CSS.
                                     Locations are set like --watch.
    -f, --force                      Recompile every Sass file, even if the CSS file is newer.
                                     Only meaningful for --update.
        --stop-on-error              If a file fails to compile, exit immediately.
                                     Only meaningful for --watch and --update.

Input and Output:
        --sass                       Use the indented Sass syntax.
        --sourcemap=TYPE             How to link generated output to the source files.
                                       auto (default): relative paths where possible, file URIs elsewhere
                                       file: always absolute file URIs
                                       inline: include the source text in the sourcemap
                                       none: no sourcemaps
    -s, --stdin                      Read input from standard input instead of an input file.
                                     This is the default if no input file is specified.
    -E, --default-encoding ENCODING  Specify the default encoding for input files.
        --unix-newlines              Use Unix-style newlines in written files.
                                     Always true on Unix.
    -g, --debug-info                 Emit output that can be used by the FireSass Firebug plugin.
    -l, --line-numbers               Emit comments in the generated CSS indicating the corresponding source line.
        --line-comments

Miscellaneous:
    -i, --interactive                Run an interactive SassScript shell.
    -c, --check                      Just check syntax, don't evaluate.
        --precision NUMBER_OF_DIGITS How many digits of precision to use when outputting decimal numbers.
                                     Defaults to 5.
        --cache-location PATH        The path to save parsed Sass files. Defaults to .sass-cache.
    -C, --no-cache                   Don't cache parsed Sass files.
        --trace                      Show a full Ruby stack trace on error.
    -q, --quiet                      Silence warnings and status messages during compilation.
```

Here's something that should work for you:

```
{
  "cmd" : ["scss", "$file", "$file_path/../css/$file_base_name.css"],
  "info" : "Building $file_path/$file_name",
  "selector": "source.scss"
}
```

Where `$file` is the full path, `$file_path` is the directory path, and `$file_base_name` is the name of your file without the extension. You can take a look at the other variables available to you [here](https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/custom-runners).

Comment: Hmmm. I'm kinda lost. I just toke the idea from a less builder. Can you clerify the issue?  / Guide me

Comment: Ok, I've added a working example (I tested it) at the end of the answer

Comment: In my project there was a `scss` folder and `css` folder side by side, you can change the destination path as you wish.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm! Is there any tutorials or info about making these builders? or at least how to understand what the helper is telling. Could be epic to remove the damn source map and make the css fully compressed

Comment: And scss @import 'test-file'; just makes _test.scss to _test.css ><

Comment: You can go ahead and add `"--sourcemap=none"` after `"scss", ` to remove sourcemaps. Unfortunately, I'm not too knowledgeable about SCSS right now, but I think you can resolve any issues by adjusting the arguments